# How make colored headrow in a table?

Tags: tables, rowcolor

I have the following table

```
\newcommand{\headrow}{\rowcolor{black!20}}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.90}
\begin{table}[ht]\rowcolors{1}{Gray}{white}
\begin{center}
\caption{Test Table}
 \begin{tabular}{l|cccccccc}
\hline
\headrow
\multirow{2}{1.7cm}{\textbf{Approach}}& \multicolumn{8}{c}{\centering \textbf{Test}}\\
\cline{2-9} 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{A}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{B}}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{C}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{D}}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{E}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{F}}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{G}}& \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{H}}\\
    \hline

   App1 & &&  && &&&
    \\ 
  App2 && &&& &&&
    \\ 
   \hline
    \end{tabular}
   
 \end{center}
\end{table}
```

Th output is the following

[image]

So as you notice, the header row has two gray colors , one  form \headrow and one from my definition of the gray color.

So, how I can have for the header the same color as one from \headrow and make the word Approch visible?

Note that, when using the nicematrix, I get the following error
[image]

Comment: Your code is not compilable. How is `\headrow` defined?

Comment: @Bernard check please

Comment: And what should have this colour?

Comment: Please help us to help you. Extend your code fragment to complete but small document, which reproduce your problem and which we can test as it is.

Comment: @Bernard This color should add the first gray color. I mean the dark gray.

Comment: So the multirow should have two colours (the upper part in a the darker grey, and the lower part in the lighter grey)?

Comment: Both shoud have the same color, the dark gray. and the last row in the table should have the light gray

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you will have a result almost perfect in the PDF viewer (for instance, you won't see the thin white lines you see in the viewers using MuPDF such as SumatraPDF).

However, you need several compilations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.90}
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Test Table}
\begin{NiceTabular}{l|cccccccc}%
  [code-before = \rowcolors{3}{}{Gray} \rowcolor{black!20}{1,2}]
\hline
\Block{2-1}{\textbf{Approach}} & \multicolumn{8}{c}{\textbf{Test}}\\
\cline{2-9} 
& \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C} & \textbf{D} & \textbf{E} & \textbf{F}
& \textbf{G} & \textbf{H} \\
\hline
App1 \\
App2 \\
\hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Ouput of the above code]

Comment: I get an error since the environment NiceTabular is not defined.

Comment: Even if we import the nicematrix package we still get the error. Note that I tested this code in overleaf

Comment: I have tried the code in Overleaf and had no error. However, there are warnings for multiply-defined labels. As of now, there are always such harmless warnings when using `\cline` in `{NiceTabular}`. I will try to avoid such warnings in a future version of `nicematrix` (I'm the author of `nicematrix`).

Comment: Im sorry. it not working and your answer is the best which im looking for. I will add the image showing the error

Comment: @user2869180: It will be easier by mail: fpantigny@wanadoo.fr

Comment: please check your inbox

Comment: I think we need to install some files in overleaf

Comment: I found the file nicematrix.sty online. So the only one error still raised is the following line in your code  [code-before = \rowcolors{3}{}{Gray} \rowcolor{black!20}{1,2}]. if we delete this line the table is generated but without the color

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution consists in adding `\multirow{-2}` at the beginning of the follwing line and adding  `\cellcolor{black!20}` inside the \multiro. Unrelated: I added the `caption` package to have a decant spacing between caption and table. I also removed all the unnecessary `\multicolumn{1}{c}{…}` in the headings row. Last remark: don't use the `center` within a table: it adds unwanted vertical spacing to the normal spacing of the table environment. environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow, caption}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\headrow}{\rowcolor{black!20}}

\begin{document}

\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.90}
\begin{table}[ht]\rowcolors{3}{}{Gray}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\centering
\caption{Test Table}
 \begin{tabular}{l|*{8}{c}}
\hline
\headrow & \multicolumn{8}{c}{\centering \textbf{Test}}\\
\cline{2-9}
\headrow \multirow{-2}{1.7cm}{\textbf{Approach}} & \textbf{A} & \textbf{B}& \textbf{C} & \textbf{D}& \textbf{E} & \textbf{F}
& \textbf{G}& \textbf{H}\\
    \hline

   App1 & && && &&&
    \\
  App2 && &&& &&&
    \\
   \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A B...H row should have the same color of dark gray

Comment: Please see the update. It makes the code still simpler.